# Can you read the value of std::atomic_flag without modifying it?

Tags: c++, multithreading, c++11, atomic

I am using C++ `std::atomic_flag` as an atomic Boolean flag. Setting the flag to true or false is not a problem but how do I query the current state of flag without setting it to some value?

I know that there are member functions '`atomic_flag_clear`' and '`atomic_flag_set`'. They do give back the previous state but also modify the current state. Is there any way to query flag state without modifying it or do I have to use full fledged '`std::atomic<bool>`'.

Comment: It would appear that its only use is to be a means of acquiring a lock. You could use a `std::atomic_flag` as a lock which you could acquire before accessing a shared resource, but if that shared resource is just a `bool` then as you said, you may as well just used `std::atomic<bool>`. _Edit:_ or rather std::atomic_bool, seeing as how they've gone to the trouble of specialising one for you!

Comment: You can't know the current state, unless you use the correct acquire/release semantics (i.e. try to lock it with `atomic_flag_set`, and then only do stuff if you actually changed the value). Simply reading it would only tell you what the value was when you read it, and it might have changed immediately afterwards.

Comment: @Mike: does that actually matter though? Sounds like all the OP wants is the ability to perform an atomic read and have some notion of ordered reads and writes.

Comment: @Rook You are right. I want to know the status at the time of read. Depending on that result I take some action. Basically in Java they have 'atomicboolean' which allows get and set 'state'.

Comment: You might also find [this other question illuminating](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9806200/how-to-atomically-negate-an-stdatomic-bool). Anyway, I think that `std::atomic_bool` and its `load()` method are probably what you want.

Comment: `std::atomic_flag` is the only atomic type which is guaranteed to be lock free according to standard. So I was inclined to use it. Not able to query the state information is hampering the use of it.

Comment: C++20 introduces [`test`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/atomic/atomic_flag/test)

Answer (score 54, accepted):

You cannot read the value of a `std::atomic_flag` without setting it to `true`. This is by design. It is not a boolean variable (we have `std::atomic<bool>` for that), but a minimal flag that is guaranteed lock free on all architectures that support C++11.

On some platforms the only atomic instructions are exchange instructions. On such platforms, `std::atomic_flag::test_and_set()` can be implemented with `exchange var,1` and `clear()` with `exchange var,0`, but there is no atomic instruction for reading the value.

So, if you want to read the value without changing it, then you need `std::atomic<bool>`.

Comment: What if I only want to print it's value for debugging purpose, so I don't really care that *this* particular read is atomic? I now use the `.__val` element for that, but it gives in error in some versions of gcc (rightfully so I guess)

Comment: You can't legitimately read the value of a `std::atomic_flag` for any purpose without modifying it. If you want to read it (even for printf debugging), you need `std::atomic<bool>`

Comment: Are there any real hardware ISAs where a 1-byte load isn't atomic, or isn't cache-coherent, or would trip hardware race detection?  Providing only TAS (test_and_set) makes sense if the only atomic **RMW** instruction is an exchange or single-bit TAS, but byte loads and byte stores are normally atomic "for free".

Comment: Perhaps there could be an ISA where pure load and pure store wouldn't provide seq_cst memory ordering, and there isn't a way to implement a separate barrier on another location?  But no, that would mean `std::atomic_thread_fence(seq_cst)` wasn't implementable, so we can rule that out.  Probably C++20's introduction of a `.test()` function on `std::atomic_flag` was motivated by reasoning like this, and didn't actually lose support for any real or plausible hardware.

Answer (score 23):

If you want to use `atomic_flag` to determine whether a thread should exit, you can do it like this:

Initialization:

```
std::atomic_flag keep_running = ATOMIC_FLAG_INIT;
keep_running.test_and_set();
```

Thread loop:

```
while (keep_running.test_and_set()) {
    // do thread stuff
}
```

When you want the thread to exit:

```
keep_running.clear();
```

Comment: Wow, I can't believe I didn't realize this possibility, to use the flag the other way around.

Comment: `while(keep_running.test_and_set())` puts an expensive atomic RMW into the loop that runs constantly.  That's really bad.  Use `std::atomic<bool>`, or C++20 `atomic_flag` `.test()`.  (@user1768761).

Comment: This keep_running or exit_now use-case doesn't need any atomic RMWs, only pure-load and pure-store, which you can get from `atomic<bool>` but not `atomic_flag`.    On ancient CPUs like m68k, `atomic<bool>` might not be lock-free, but that's not a relevant concern on normal CPUs.  If it was, you'd have to roll your own pure-load/pure-store with `volatile bool`, which is UB in ISO C++ but works on real-world compilers because CPUs have coherent caches.  (You don't need any ordering wrt. other data, just visibility.)  I wouldn't recommend volatile unless you're actually using m68k or something.

Answer (score 7):

With C++20 we got the [`test()`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/atomic/atomic_flag/test) method, which does exactly what OP wants.

Comment: I know the question is flagged with `c++11`, but it is also very old. Just added for completeness.