# Test and Test-and-set in c++

Tags: c++, multithreading, synchronization, locking

I am trying to implement Test and Test-and-set in c++.

as per [C++ atomic_flag query state](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11099601/c-atomic-flag-query-state)
we cannot check the flag state, so whats the workaround for that

loop will be like this

```
std::atomic_flag lock_stream = ATOMIC_FLAG_INIT;
void ttas_lock()
{
    while(lock_Stream);
    while(lock_stream.test_and_set());
    return
}
```

error: could not convert ‘((ttas*)this)->ttas::lock_stream’ from ‘std::atomic_flag’ to ‘bool’
         while(lock_stream)

Comment: you code isn't clear, do you want to change it from false to true once, and return?

Comment: if lock=false while loop breaks, then i test and set, if false returned i get the lock, wanted to know how to check lock_Stream state, defined as    std::atomic_flag lock_stream = ATOMIC_FLAG_INIT;

Comment: it sounds like you just want to use a mutex with unique_lock?

Comment: yes, trying to implement TTAS https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Test_and_Test-and-set

Answer (score 2):

If you want to test lock_stream without setting it, you should use `std::atomic<bool>`.

Therefore, declare it as:

```
std::atomic<bool> lock_stream = ATOMIC_FLAG_INIT;
```

Instead of test and set, you just use exchange:

```
void ttas_lock()
{
    while(lock_stream);
    while(lock_stream.exchange(true)); // this is equivalent to test and set
    return;
}
```

According to wikipedia, if test and set fails, you should do the test again, which results in:

```
void ttas_lock()
{
    do {
        while (lock_stream) continue;
    } while (lock_stream.exchange(true)); // actual atomic locking
    return;
}
```

Comment: is there any workaround with test and set instruction?

Comment: The exchange is the same as test and set, think of `atomic_flag` as a wrapper around `atomic<bool>`

Comment: @J.S No. Some hardware can't necessarily implement the functionality you're looking for, and `atomic_flag` was designed to be the absolutely lowest common denominator. You probably shouldn't use it unless either you're targeting such hardware or what you want to do can be efficiently implemented with it.

Comment: @ all Thanks, I implemented using exchange and bool.

Answer (score 0):

Your function:

```
void ttas_lock()
{
    while(lock_Stream);
    if(!lock_stream.test_and_set()) return;
}
```

will *always* `return` after `lock_Stream` is `false`.  Not what you want.

Comment: asgn2.cpp:84:15: error: could not convert ‘((ttas*)this)->ttas::lock_stream’ from ‘std::atomic_flag’ to ‘bool’
         while(lock_stream). 
how to read atomic flag value?

Comment: @J.S because you want : `std::atomic<bool> lock_Stream = ATOMIC_FLAG_INIT;` and then ` while (lock_Stream.test_and_set(std::memory_order_acquire));` then at some later point `lock_Stream.clear(std::memory_order_release);`

Comment: can you please explain

Comment: please see [std::atomic_flag](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/atomic/atomic_flag)