# Stopping a thread using an `atomic_flag` variable

Tags: multithreading, c++11

This is related to the second answer to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11099601/c-atomic-flag-query-state) question.

My test code is below. I'm trying to launch a thread, and then to make it stop using the `std::atomic_flag`. Then the thread should output a number of loop executions and total duration, and stop.

```
std::atomic_flag keepRunning = ATOMIC_FLAG_INIT;

void F()
{
  keepRunning.test_and_set();
  long long unsigned count = 0;
  const time_t start = time(nullptr);
  while (keepRunning.test_and_set())
  {
    std::cout << '.';
    ++count;
  }
  const time_t duration = time(nullptr) - start;
  std::cout << count << '\t' << duration << std::endl;
}

int main()
{
  std::thread t(F);
  keepRunning.clear();
  t.join();
}
```

The problem is that the thread **doesn't stop**.

Why is that?

- Compiler: g++ (Ubuntu 4.8.4-2ubuntu1~14.04.3) 4.8.4
- OS: guest OS Ubuntu 14.04 on the macOS Sierra Ver 10.12.2 host
- Compilation flags - I tried `-O0` and `-O4`, and it didn't make any difference.

Comment: @andrewrk - can you please look at this question?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In your `F()` you ignore the output from the first `keepRunning.test_and_set()`. Your attempt to initialize the flag there causes a race with the `keepRunning.clear()` statement in `main()`. Depending on which of these statements runs first you either get the intended behavior or have ignored `clear()` call and a never ending thread.

By the time `F()` had a chance to run, the flag should be already initialized with the correct value. Moving that initial `test_and_set()` into `main()` prevents the race:

```
std::atomic_flag keepRunning = ATOMIC_FLAG_INIT;

void F()
{
  long long unsigned count = 0;
  const time_t start = time(nullptr);
  while (keepRunning.test_and_set())
  {
    std::cout << '.';
    ++count;
  }
  const time_t duration = time(nullptr) - start;
  std::cout << count << '\t' << duration << std::endl;
}

int main()
{
  keepRunning.test_and_set();
  std::thread t(F);
  keepRunning.clear();
  t.join();
}
```

Now the flag is effectively only changed in main() and only "read" in `F()`.

Answer (score 2):

It does not stop (most of the time) because the loop in `F` will probably never see a cleared flag.

Assuming that the creation of a `thread` will take some time, `keepRunning.clear()` in `main` is likely to run first.
When `F` finally gets to run, it immediately sets the value and enters a loop that will never see a cleared flag and therefore never quits.

Instead of initially setting the flag value in `F`, a solution is to initialize it to `true`. However, `std::atomic_flag` does not let you do that because of its limited interface (this design is on purpose,`std::atomic_flag` is supposed to be used as a low-level building block for other primitives).

You could use a `std::atomic<bool>`, initialize it to `true` and remove the initial `store(true)` in `F`. For demo purposes, I added a `sleep_for` statement before clearing the flag in `main`.

```
std::atomic<bool> keepRunning{true};

void F()
{
  long long unsigned count = 0;
  const time_t start = time(nullptr);
  while (keepRunning)
  {
    std::cout << '.';
    ++count;
  }
  const time_t duration = time(nullptr) - start;
  std::cout << count << '\t' << duration << std::endl;
}

int main()
{
  std::thread t(F);
  std::this_thread::sleep_for(1s); // optional
  keepRunning = false;
  t.join();
}
```